# Post-Redirect-Get

Tags: javascript, form-submit, reload

I am reloading/refreshing a page using `javascript` method `document.location.reload()`.
I am getting the alert message :

```
The browser needs to resend the information
```

How can I avoid this alert message and reload my page ?

Comment: Is the initial page load the result of a POST? If so, it's a security thing to stop people from accidentally submitting the same information twice.

Comment: you miss the Redirect step, you shoud not reload() a POSTed but rather open a new different location with GET-only parameters. that's the whole point of "PRG"

Comment: Yes the initial page is sending POST request.
I am using <h:form></h:form> tag in JSP page.
If I do reload, It will take to that page, But i want me page to be updated with contents on refresh

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to do a complete reload, including sending the previously POSTed data to the server?  If you need to 'reload' the result of a POST then you can't do it without the warning message, however if you just want to GET the same page again you can use `window.location = window.location;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Almost all browsers have an alert like that upon reload because of forms posts.

If a purchase was made online, more likely than not it would use a form. If that form got resubmitted it could cause the payment to occur again. This is why we get warnings from out browsers, to stop us accidentally resubmitting forms.

I would recommend that, after you have submitted your form successfully, redirect your page to itself without resubmitting the form. Then you can reload to your hearts content.